# Password protected download link

Tags: javascript, html, hyperlink

I want to make a simple password protected link that enables users (with the correct password) to download a zip file. The link, as in the code below, is "folder/history.zip". The link is a simple text ("Open"), not a button. I don't have any experience with javascript. The problem is that the password protection does not work when I tried. I just want to know how can I edit the code below to make it work?.. I don't have any experience with javascript so I appreciate any help!

html:

```
<a href="folder/history.zip">open</a>
```

Javascript:

```
<SCRIPT type="text/javascript">
    function passWord() {
        var testV = 1;
        var pass1 = prompt('Please Enter Your Password',' ');
        while (testV < 3) {
        if (!pass1)
            history.go(-1);
        if (pass1.toLowerCase() == "teacher") {
            alert('You Got it Right!');
            window.open('folder/history.zip');
            break;
        }
        testV+=1;
        var pass1 = prompt('Access Denied - Password Incorrect, Please Try Again.','Password');
    }
    if (pass1.toLowerCase()!="password" & testV ==3)
        history.go(-1);
    return " ";
}
</SCRIPT>
<CENTER>
    <FORM>
        <input type="text" value="Enter Protected Area" onClick="passWord()">
    </FORM>
</CENTER>
```

Comment: That is nowhere near a sufficient password protection. The file needs to be password protected **on the server**. As long as I can simply type the file's direct URL into my browser and download it, it is **not** protected. And both the direct URL *and* the password required for your little check here are plainly visible in the Javascript itself, which is visible to anyone bothering to look.

Comment: I know it is not a good way to protect a link, but I am not looking for something more than this. I just want the password popup box to open.

Comment: Is there an error on the browser's JavaScript console?

Comment: I am assuming that because, it is not working. When I test it and click on the link, the password popup box doesn't open.

Comment: Have you looked at your browser's Javascript console for errors? Typically you can open it with Ctrl+Alt+C...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try the below code,

**JS:**

```
 function passwd(){

  var password = prompt('Enter the password to download the file:');
  if(password.toLowerCase() == "teacher"){
    window.open("folder/history.zip")    
  }else{
    alert("incorrect password!! please try again");
  }
}
```

**HTML**

```
<input type="button" value="download zip file" onClick="passwd()"/>
```